# Justify space between vertically to fill all available space

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am trying to do a component that has 4 fields, two on the right and two on the left, I have them spaced horizontally but I have not been able to do the same vertically.

Here's the code:

```html
<div class="flex min-h-[3em] bg-blue-500 justify-between">
    <div class="flex flex-col h-full justify-between w-20">
        <span>
            This long content should be on the top left corner, it is long to ilustrate my point with a short width so it grows more vertically
        </span>
        <span>This should be on the left corner</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col h-full justify-between">
        <span>This is on the top left corner</span>
        <span> This should be at the bottom right corner </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just want to fill the space vertical space between the `span` elements.

It seems to be impossible to achieve this the way I want, but it doesn't have to be using divs like I am here.

I want to have each of the 4 fields on each corner of the container, the reason I don't do it with position absolute is because I want them to have "collision" with each other so they don't overlap.

Comment: I think this is a structure issue. There is no real method of aligning elements that do not share a parent. If the structure can be changed then this gets much simpler. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dyadeKz?editors=1100

Comment: Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a structure issue. There is no real method of aligning elements that do not share a parent. If the structure can be changed then this gets much simpler.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

div div {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  width: 40%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="flex bg-blue-500 justify-between">
  <div class="flex h-full justify-between w-full">
    <span>Some long content to ilustrate my point with a short width so it grows more vertically</span>
    <span>This is on the top left corner</span>
    <span>This should be on the bottom  left corner</span>
    <span> This should be at the bottom right corner </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was able to fix it with pure tailwind, I just had to add `flex-wrap` to the second div and it worked as expected, thanks.

Comment: The only issue is that now I need to set the width for this to work, but I think I can work with that

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking at your code and noticed that there was a small typo in the span tag.

You should use the class mb-2, which adds a margin to the left.

Try this:

```
<div class="flex min-h-[5em] bg-blue-500 justify-between">
    <div class="flex flex-col h-full justify-between w-full">
        <span class="mb-2"> Title </span>
        <span class="mb-2"> Person </span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col h-full justify-between">
        <span class="mb-2"> 100 </span>
        <span class="mb-2"> 12/20 </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since you do not want to do it manually, use flex-grow:

```
<div class="flex min-h-[5em] bg-blue-500 justify-between">
    <div class="flex flex-col h-full justify-between flex-grow">
        <span> Title </span>
        <span> Person </span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col h-full justify-between flex-grow">
        <span> 100 </span>
        <span> 12/20 </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I want, I don't want to have to set the space manually, and in that case I would just use gap instead of margin, I want the elements to be separated by all the remaining space

Comment: Christopher check out my edit.

Comment: It looks like that still doesn't solve it

Answer (score 0):

set the height to `full` as well

```
   <div class="flex min-h-[5em] h-full bg-blue-500 justify-between">
        <div class="flex flex-col justify-between">
          <span> Title </span>
          <span>Person</span>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col justify-between">
          <span>100</span>
          <span> 12/20 </span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work since it makes the height fixed, and I need it to grow with the contents

Comment: i've modified it

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work since the container grows to fill the hole page

Answer (score 0):

Add min-height: inherit; to component give the same height as the parent div

Hopefully, this will work

```
<style>
.component {
  min-height: inherit;
}
</style>
<div class="flex min-h-[5em] bg-blue-500 justify-between">
  <div class="flex component flex-col h-full justify-between w-full">
    <span> Title </span>
    <span>Person</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex component flex-col h-full justify-between">
    <span>100</span>
    <span> 12/20 </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought this one had solved it but the issue is that if one of the two left and right divs grows larger than the min height the other one wont grow to fill that space

Answer (score -1):

You have given a min-h, but for justify-between it is unable to get a default height

Give a default height value (h-full in this case)

*div* class="... min-h-[5em] **h-full** ... justify-between.."

```
  <div class="flex min-h-[5em] h-full bg-blue-500 justify-between flex-row">
    <div class="flex flex-col justify-between">
      <span> Title </span>
      <span>Person</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col justify-between  ">
      <span>100</span>
      <span> 12/20 </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this makes some sense.

Comment: Yes this tecnically works but I can't set the height to 100% since it messes with the component, It needs to have a minimum height and then grow to fit it's contents if they are larger than the set height. If I set another arbitrary value for height like `h-20` it doesn't grow when the contents overflow

Comment: @ChristopherPoulsen hmm, tbh I don't get it. maybe try flex-grow? a visual represention might help others if they are try and help until then someone else might be able to provide an answer.